# Error after upgrading Android Studio to 0.6

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading to Android Studio 0.6 I had an error:

> Error:No signature of method: `com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin.getRuntimeJarList()` is applicable for argument types: `()` values: `[]`

Comment: what other plugins do you use?

Comment: Please add your build files to your question.

Comment: I use Robolectric as well but the difference is probably that I use version 2.3

Comment: I am also using Robolectric and have the same issue. I use classpath 'com.novoda.gradle:robolectric-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' for my Robolectric integration. Removing this plugin removes the error, but unfortunately I need that plugin. Made issue https://github.com/novoda/robolectric-plugin/issues/15